# Grouping data by Start/Enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row, gaps-and-islands

I have following dataset.

| Product | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:37:44.717 |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:38:39.403 |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:39:34.447 |
| B | 2023-12-27 22:40:28.733 |
| B | 2023-12-27 22:41:21.460 |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:43:09.917 |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:44:06.500 |
| C | 2023-12-27 22:44:59.263 |
| C | 2023-12-27 22:45:53.230 |
| C | 2023-12-27 22:46:46.597 |
| B | 2023-12-27 22:46:52.164 |
| B | 2023-12-27 22:47:54.531 |

I want to group by Product and display the min Timestamp and max Timestamp as StartDate/EndDate.
But it shouldn´t ingore that the products changes.
The desired output should look like this one.

| Product | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:37:44.717 | 2023-12-27 22:39:34.447 |
| B | 2023-12-27 22:40:28.733 | 2023-12-27 22:41:21.460 |
| A | 2023-12-27 22:43:09.917 | 2023-12-27 22:44:06.500 |
| C | 2023-12-27 22:44:59.263 | 2023-12-27 22:46:46.597 |
| B | 2023-12-27 22:46:52.164 | 2023-12-27 22:47:54.531 |

All my attempts failed miserably

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION` to do that. Here is sample code

```
WITH GroupedData AS (
    SELECT
        Product,
        [Timestamp],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS prn
    FROM
        TempDataset
)    
SELECT
    Product,
    MIN([Timestamp]) AS StartDate,
    MAX([Timestamp]) AS EndDate
FROM
    GroupedData
GROUP BY
    Product,
    (rn - prn)
ORDER BY
    MIN([Timestamp]);
```

Here is [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/of0nwwBB)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gaps and islands solution as follows:

```
SELECT T.PRODUCT,
    MIN(T.TIMESTAMP) AS MIN_TIMESTAMP, 
    MAX(T.TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP
FROM (
    SELECT T.*, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN T.PRODUCT = T.PREV_PROD THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
            OVER (ORDER BY T.TIMESTAMP) AS SM 
    FROM (
        SELECT T.*,
            LAG(T.PRODUCT) OVER (ORDER BY T.TIMESTAMP) AS PREV_PROD
        FROM YOUR_TABLE T
    ) T
) T
GROUP BY T.SM, T.PRODUCT
ORDER BY MIN(T.TIMESTAMP), T.PRODUCT
```

Comment: You could certainly improve your layout... Very hard to make sense of.

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the error
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Column 'T.PRODUCT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The first subquery uses `sum` without a `group by`.  Could fix it like `SUM(CASE WHEN PRODUCT = PREV_PROD THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  AS SM `

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that. please check the updated answer

Comment: Cool, today I learned you can omit `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` :)

Comment: In my fiddle, you can't `ORDER BY T.MIN_TIMESTAMP, T.PRODUCT` . You can change to `ORDER BY MIN(T.TIMESTAMP), T.PRODUCT`. Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/SiPLyuEO)

Answer (score 0):

The process is to create two rank blocks of timestamps. the first one by partitioning the product and other one without it. Then subtract two rank blocks and we get group numbers. Then simply select product, min and max timestamp for every group number.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    A.*
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.TIMESTAMP) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.PRODUCT ORDER BY A.TIMESTAMP) AS GROUP_RANK
FROM
    prd A
)

SELECT
    CTE.Product
    ,MIN(CTE.TIMESTAMP) AS START_TIME
    ,MAX(CTE.TIMESTAMP) AS END_TIME
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    CTE.Product
    ,CTE.GROUP_RANK
```